# Using a constexpr method inside another method of the same class in C++

Tags: c++

As expected, I can compile the sample below without any problems

```
// first_sample.cpp
struct sample_struct
{
    constexpr int 
    sample_method() 
    { return 5; }
};

int main() 
{
    sample_struct sample_object;
    constexpr int sample_variable = sample_object.sample_method();
    return 0;
}
```

But i cannot compile the following sample for the reason

> 'this' is not a constant expression

```
// second_sample.cpp
struct sample_struct
{
    constexpr int 
    sample_method_first() 
    { return 5; }

    void 
    sample_method_second() 
    {   constexpr int sample_variable = sample_method_first(); 
        /* Do something with sample_variable */ }
};

int main() 
{ return 0; }
```

I already know how to solve this *"problem"* so i am not asking for a solution.
I am asking for a reasonable explanation why i am allowed to call a constexpr method from a
non-constexpr object **while i am not allowed** to call the same constexpr method inside another method (from non-constexpr 'this').

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the C++ Standard, [dcl.constexpr]/9:

> A constexpr specifier used in an object declaration declares the object as const. Such an object shall have literal type and shall be initialized. [...] Otherwise, or if a constexpr specifier is used in a reference declaration, every full-expression that appears in its initializer shall be a constant expression.

Now, the compiler implicitly adds a `this->` to the member function call, as specified by [expr.call]/1

> In the case of an implicit class member access, the implied object is the one pointed to by this. [Note: a member function call of the form `f()` is interpreted as `(*this).f()` (see 9.3.1). —end note ]

As [jogojapan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/777186/jogojapan) has pointed out (see [chat discussion](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32920/discussion-between-dyp-and-jogojapan)), in the official C++11 Standard, `this` may occur as postfix-expression in a class member access as per [expr.const]/2, which is the case here. But the resolution of [Issue 1369](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1369) disallowed any use of `this` in constant expressions; however function invocation substitution can allow using `this` within the context of a `constexpr` function by replacing it with a prvalue pointer.

The C++14 draft removes the sub-paragraph about *function invocation substitution* in favour of an exception to [expr.const]/2, explicitly allowing the use of `this` within the context of a `constexpr` function (in this case effectively the same as what function invocation substitution allowed).

---

Well, this isn't very "reasonable" as it doesn't provide the *reason why it is specified in this way*, it only provides the reason why the compiler rejects it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32920/discussion-between-dyp-and-jogojapan)

Answer (score 0):

A `constexpr` function may be called in any context, constant expression or not. (And your `sample_method_second` isn't even `constexpr`.) But a `constexpr` object must be evaluated at compile time.

So what `sample_method_second` does is ask the compiler to use `this` to get the result of `sample_method_first` at compile time. Clearly that's impossible.

The difference is that in the first example, the scope of `main` allows the compiler to call the method *on `sample_object`*. But being able to evaluate the value of one object does not extend to all potential objects in the program, which is what `sample_method_second` does.

The solution (well, aside from making `sample_method_first` independent of `this` using `static`) is not to declare `sample_variable` as `constexpr`. If you're using it in a way that requires `constexpr`, then your design is flawed because the one member function would actually need multiple (potentially infinite) implementations in the final program.

Remember, each potential different value of a legitimately `constexpr` variable may produce a new template instantiation, a differently-organized `switch`, or halt compilation with a `static_assert`. Try doing that retroactively at runtime!

---

As for why the first case is allowed:

```
sample_struct sample_object;
constexpr int sample_variable = sample_object.sample_method();
```

What's happening here is `constexpr` function invocation, and the rule for that excludes

> — an invocation of a function other than a constexpr constructor for a literal class, a constexpr function, or an implicit invocation of a trivial destructor (12.4)

There simply isn't a requirement that the object be `constexpr` because if something needs to be constant to evaluate the inside of the function, or use the result of the function, the evaluation will go awry according to one of the other rules such as lvalue-to-rvalue conversion. You won't be able to modify `sample_method` to actually access anything, and doing so will complain that `sample_object` is not declared `constexpr`, or that its address is not constant if you try to use the value of `this` directly.

Comment: But the value of `this` isn't required for the evaluation of `this->sample_method_first()`. Isn't it possible for the compiler to determine that?

Comment: @DyP No. Anyway the compiler wouldn't be determining that; the language standard would. If you don't want a function to use `this`, then declare it `static`.

Comment: What about something like this `constexpr int sample_method_first(bool b) { return b?5:this->member; }`?

Comment: I don't quite follow this explanation. You are saying that `sample_object.sample_method()` is possible, because it implies the evaluation of just one object, rather than the potential evaluation of all objects that `this` may refer to inside the definition of `sample_method()`. Yet it shouldn't matter how many different objects may be evaluated. What should matter is whether or not the expression being evaluated is a `constexpr`. And `sample_object` isn't.

Comment: @DyP You're missing the point… mentioning `this` is sufficient to render an expression non-constant. `this` is mentioned before you call `sample_method_first`, it doesn't matter what's inside it.

Comment: @jogojapan: Actually, `sample_object` is a core constant expression, as long as the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion is not applied to it.

Comment: @aschepler That makes sense for a global variable but this is a local. Actually this looks like a compiler bug to me, I hadn't noticed the lack of a `constexpr` there.

Comment: @aschepler Yes, I think that is the reason why `sample_object` can be used in this way. But the answer above doesn't say anything about that.

Comment: @Potatoswatter Yes of course, but that's not a problem the compiler couldn't overcome as far as I can see. I know it's forbidden by the Standard, but that's not the question.

Comment: Yeah, this isn't really logically impossible, just a consequence of the way the Standard is worded.  I can imagine a few additions which would change things: make the object expression for a static member access a discarded-expression, and allow `this` in a constant expression if it is a discarded subexpression.

Comment: Nope, not a compiler bug. I'll check this out a bit further and update the answer.